# What are the upper limits of Cyclops' Optic Blast?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

I feel like nothing would be able to survive an un-visored optic blast stare down, but what are Scotts limits?

Comment: +1 for the line: *un-visored optic blast stare down*

Comment: But how come his visor can withstand that energy? Could you make a Cyclops-proof armor from that material?

Answer (score 14):

Two Gigawatts:

> Cyclops' force beams were measured by Iron Man to be almost 2 Gigawatts.

#### ~Civil War: X-Men #4

Cyclops has shown the power of his optic blast by blasting through the walls of a hardened building, tunneling through solid rock, and blowing the top off a mountain. He has also been able to knock Thor's (the strongest current Asgardian) hammer out of his hands.

Comment: Wow. For reference, this is about as much power as two nuclear plants running at once, or about enough to power half of Belgium.

Comment: Oh, good, plenty strong enough to power the flux capacitor.

Comment: @Pureferret - It looks like Spenser took a walk but I'll bump you 10 for a good answer.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Or enough power to run about 1 and 7/8 deLorean Time Machines.

Answer (score -1):

Not to mention Cyclops blew off Wolverine's arm in the future (I'm not sure about the comic), Adamantium and all.  As far as we know, nothing can destroy Adamantium... until Scott.

Comment: Technically, while Wolverine's bones are covered with Adamantium, his joints are not. So with the correct amount of precision, it should be technically possible to split Wolverine anywhere two joints come together. With the force Cyclops is able to project and his level of pinpoint accuracy he should be able to tear Wolverine apart at the joints and cleanly separate them. Wolverine would of course be able to regenerate or reattach the limb but it would certainly be...unpleasant.

Answer (score -1):

I can't be sure, this is just a long forgotten memory, but I believe that there were two beams, in the Mutant arsenal, that could cut Adamantium.  Scotts optic blast, and Dazzlers laser projection at maximum output.  Since Scotts blast only produce force and not heat that must be very powerful (when focused to pinpoint accuracy) indeed.