# How does Cyclops' Visor work to hold massive optic blast force?

Tags: marvel, x-men, cyclops

Due to head injuries, Cyclops can't control his optic blasts at will. So, he wears Visor to prevent unwanted damages of his surrounding.

In *Civil War: X-Men #4*, Ironman measured Cyclops' optic blast beam to be almost 2 Gigawatts which is able to knock Thor's hammer out of his hand ([source](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/what-are-the-upper-limits-of-cyclops-optic-blast)).

That amount of force can easily knock any Cyclops' wearable eye gadget out with his skin if it wasn't easy to take out. How exactly does Visor work technically?

Comment: It's made of almost pure plot-onium. When it was first forged, it took nearly 300 hack scriptwriters 19 days and 19 nights to bend its internal logical inconsistencies to their will.

Comment: The question isn't duplicate by any way. That question is dealing with color, but this one with force. This makes the question different. The answer there also present several points without specific point which could be answer to this. Don't ruin user experience by closing it as duplicate.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that Cyclops first appeared in 1963 in X-Men #1 as a creation of Stan Lee and Jack Kirby. They're awesome, don't get me wrong, but their science fiction from those days was extremely creative but not always . . . sensible? Like how do the vital organs function for Thing, Mr. Fantastic, and Human Torch? (like Jonny's "supernova" heat would cause his internal water to kill him with steam lol, or at least he'd dehydrate).EDIT---whups, I hit enter. I was going to say that the visor was so iconic for Cyclops that there's no going back!!!

Comment: @SachinShekhar The answer you've accepted says exactly the same thing as the answer to that other question, even explicitly acknowledging that other question, but you're not convinced it's a duplicate?

Comment: I voted to close for another reason, I think it goes with the reason used by the first to VTC. I don't think it's salvageable, or I would have attempted to edit it. I could be wrong, maybe there was an issue of the comic book that went into detail, but I don't think an answer is possible here. Surely Thaddeus would have dropped a 19-page answer on you if there were one. Sorry, nothing personal.

Comment: @Anthony Thaddeus has included that irrelevant point in that answer, it doesn't make this question a duplicate. Otherwise, you'd end up with closing many questions based on Thaddeus' long answer. Nothing personal..

Comment: @JohnO It goes with the reason that had the most votes, unless there's a 2-2-1 tie (in which case I think it uses the first close reason). I'm not sure if moderator close votes change that in any way.

Comment: @SachinShekhar You accepted an answer that essentially boils down to the "irrelevant point" in Thaddeus' answer (you even went as far as to edit that answer to bring attention to that one sentence) to that other question; that's the very definition of a duplicate on the SE network.

Comment: @Anthony That point is relevant here, and irrelevant there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_(comics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_%28comics%29)

> Cyclops' body is naturally immune to the beams' force.[110] His mind projects a psionic field that envelops his body rendering it immune to his optic beam, allowing him to shut it off by simply closing his eyes. Scott is also immune to the power of his brother Alex (Havok) who has the ability to emit waves of energy that heat the air into plasma. Likewise Havok has demonstrated immunity to Cyclops' optic beam. Scott has been shown as being able to absorb Storm's lightning bolt, although this act caused Cyclops a great deal of pain.[111] The ruby quartz used in his battle visor has been said to be resonate with his body's psionic field. Scott has only a limited resistance to his brother Vulcan's powers.
>
> For all Cyclops' skill in manipulating his optic beam, it continuously projects from his eyes whenever they are open and unprotected. To prevent the destruction of any objects in his field of view, Cyclops uses a pair of ruby quartz eye glasses developed by Professor X to contain the devastating rays. In his X-Men uniform he uses a ruby quartz battle visor in place of the glasses. **The crystal is said to resonate at the same frequency as the psionic field that protects Cyclops (and Havok) from their own powers.** [volume & issue needed] His uniform has firing studs incorporated into his gloves and on the sides of the battle visor that control the visor's aperture. In the event that the visor has a power failure, the apertures are spring loaded to automatically close so Cyclops can at least see normally. He has also been observed using casual sunglasses and contact lenses made from the same ruby quartz as his visor lens.[112]

Unforunately, the section on the ruby resonation has no volume/issue citation. This resonance is also referenced in [SciFi.SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27303/cyclops-visor-material-and-beam-color/27307#27307).  So somehow, this makes the visor also immune to the force blasts.

Answer (score -2):

The visor could be polarized such that the color of light (i.e. the wavelength of the light) that Scott shoots out is blocked by the visor. Essentially, it's like a super specialized pair of sunglasses.

Comment: Cyclops' optic beam isn't electromagnetic wave. See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24723/is-the-red-beam-coming-out-of-cyclops-eye-a-laser-beam/24725#24725